# Reflection in mirror - ingore boolean operator

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm working on a interior design of a room. To position a camera I have removed one wall of the room using boolean operator. I want a mirror I have in a room to ignore this and reflect the wall not HDRI texture which I used.

[image]

As you can see in a mirror (on the right of the window) there is a HDRI in a reflection however the room is closed, there should be only wall.

Sub-question: If above is possible to achieve. On the hidden wall there is also some furniture as you can see on the render from different angle.
[image]
Those objects are hidden but is it possible to display them in reflection?

Thank you.

Comment: if you're using Cycles, you can select your wall object, go into the Object panel > Visibility, disable Camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the wall a separate object and unclick the camera option under the visibility section. The object will became invisible for camera but stays in render.
[image]
Here I have a box with mirror and a light inside and camera in font of the wall. As soon as you uncheck the camera in visibility the wall is gone but stays in the mirror reflection. Using cycles render.